# Linq query fine tuning

Tags: c#, linq

Query logic is Grouping the items by Id and Ordering it by Id. Then inside grouped items Ordering by Item1 then by Item2.

Linq query below,

```
var group1Items = MyList.GroupBy(g => g.Id)
                        .Where(w => w.Any(a => a.Code = 1)
                        .Select(s => new 
                                    { key = s.Key, 
                                      items = s.OrderBy(o => o.Item1)
                                               .ThenBy(t => t.Item2)
                                     }
                                )
                                .OrderBy(o => o.Id)
                                .SelectMany(sm => sm.Items).ToList();

     var group2Items = MyList.GroupBy(g => g.Id)
                        .Where(w => w.Any(a => a.Code = 2)
                        .Select(s => new 
                                    { key = s.Key, 
                                      items = s.OrderBy(o => o.Item1)
                                               .ThenBy(t => t.Item2)
                                     }
                                )
                                .OrderBy(o => o.Id)
                                .SelectMany(sm => sm.Items).ToList();

   MyList.Clear();
   MyList.InsertRange(Mylist.Count, group1Items);
   MyList.InsertRange(Mylist.Count, group2Items);
```

In the above two queries, only difference is Where condition. Is it possible to rewrite into single query?

Comment: Why don't you use && or || operator to combine the where condition into single condition?

Comment: Your code above seems prone to creating duplicates if any `Id` value is found with both `Code == 1` and `Code == 2`.  Is this a desired result?  If you don't need the dups it can probably be done in a single query, otherwise it's going to be two queries concatenated.

Comment: shouldn't this be in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed where clause in the LINQ expression and implemented at InsertRange() method. This avoids redundant queries

```
 var groupItems = MyList
                    .GroupBy(g => g.Id)
                    .Select(s => new 
                                { key = s.Key, 
                                  items = s.OrderBy(o => o.Item1)
                                           .ThenBy(t => t.Item2)
                                 }
                            )
                            .OrderBy(o => o.Id)
                            .SelectMany(sm => sm.Items).ToList();


 MyList.Clear();
 MyList.InsertRange(Mylist.Count, groupItems.Where(w => w.Code == 1));
 MyList.InsertRange(Mylist.Count, groupItems.Where(w => w.Code == 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Single query:

```
var groupItems = MyList.GroupBy(g => g.Id)
                        .Where(w => w.Any(a => a.Code == 1 || a.Code == 2)
                        .Select(s => new 
                                    { key = s.Key, 
                                      items = s.OrderBy(o => o.Item1)
                                               .ThenBy(t => t.Item2)
                                     }
                                )
                                .OrderBy(o => o.Id)
                                .SelectMany(sm => sm.Items).ToList();
```

If Code 1 must come before Code 2:

```
var groupItems = MyList.GroupBy(g => g.Id)
                        .Where(w => w.Any(a => a.Code == 1)
                        .Select(s => new 
                                    { key = s.Key, 
                                      items = s.OrderBy(o => o.Item1)
                                               .ThenBy(t => t.Item2)
                                     }
                                )
                                .OrderBy(o => o.Id)
                                .SelectMany(sm => sm.Items)
                  .Union(MyList.GroupBy(g => g.Id)
                        .Where(w => w.Any(a => a.Code == 2)
                        .Select(s => new 
                                    { key = s.Key, 
                                      items = s.OrderBy(o => o.Item1)
                                               .ThenBy(t => t.Item2)
                                     }
                                )
                                .OrderBy(o => o.Id)
                                .SelectMany(sm => sm.Items)).ToList();
```

Comment: I think the order of items may be different  - original will get all `a.Code == 1` first, this will have mix for 1/2. It may not matter in this case if items have unique Id...

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't realise that you wanted them ordered like that. Can you OrderBy the Code property and ThenBy Id property?

Comment: No, I can't do that. It will change the sorting sequence.

Comment: So you want all of the GroupItems containing Code1 items first, ordered by ID, followed by all Code2 items, ordered by ID?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I disagree. It should work fine. But the orderby needs to be changed to `o.key`

Comment: Thanks Glen, it worked well. But still the ordering Items inside the group makes repeated code. Can we make it still cleaner?

Comment: I think we can, I'll take another look at it

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to avoid code duplication it may be easiest to capture a variable holding the code by which to filter.

```
int code = 0;  // initialize with any value
var groupItems = MyList.GroupBy(g => g.Id)
    .Where(w => w.Any(a => a.Code == code)
    .Select(s => new
    {
        key = s.Key,
        items = s.OrderBy(o => o.Item1)
                    .ThenBy(t => t.Item2)
    })
    .OrderBy(o => o.Id)
    .SelectMany(sm => sm.Items);  // No ToList() here!

MyList.Clear();
code = 1;
MyList.InsertRange(Mylist.Count, groupItems.ToList());
code = 2;
MyList.InsertRange(Mylist.Count, groupItems.ToList());
```